# What is the different between Attributes in Entity Diagrams and Attributes in Relations.

Tags: mysql, relational-database, entity-relationship

In the The Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD), Columns are attributes that belong to the entity modeled by the table.

But what is the different between these attributes in Entity Diagrams and Attributes in Relations in Database.

Comment: What exact kind of ERD are you talking about, eg a tool/product? There are no columns in an ER diagram. Although there are columns in diagrams that *claim* to be ER but are really just diagrams describing a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes in the ER model are mappings from entity sets or relationship sets to value sets. That means non-key ER attributes are represented by a key/value column pair in a physical model/database, not just a single column.

Attributes in the relational model correspond with roles in the predicate of the relation (key or not). These are generally represented by individual columns, but the components of a logical relation need not correspond one-to-one with the elements of a physical model. A logical date *could* be represented by 3 int columns. A set of true/false attributes *could* be represented as a single bit field.